# Django ORM data based on max date group

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

model

```
class quote(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(stock, related_name='stock', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30,decimal_places=5)
    valid_till = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField() #time
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

ex data

```
id stock price valid_till created_at
1. 1.    200.  09 April.   09 April 
2. 1.    300.  10 April.   09 April 
3. 2.    100.  07 April.   07 April 
4. 2.    200.  08 April.   08 April
```

output desire

```
id stock price valid_till created_at
2. 1.    300.  10 April.   09 April 
4. 2.    200.  08 April.   08 April
```

I need only record for max date of every stock

currently doing
quote.objects.values('stock__symbol').annotate(max_date=Max('valid_till'))

but still not able to think about proper solution

Comment: do you want all the quotes with their stocks by max date?

Comment: yes i want max by their stock max date

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods to get the quote(s) with max date. Using that queryset you can then find whatever related model instances you need.

1. Find max value using aggregate() method, then query filtering the max value

```
# returns a dict containing your max_date
aggregation = quote.objects.aggregate(max_date=Max('valid_till'))

# get max_date from dict
max_date = aggregation['max_date']

#filter quotes based on max_date
max_date_quotes = quote.objects.filter(valid_till = max_date)
```

2. Order by valid_till. This assumes you have a single max date.

```
max_date_quote = quote.objects.all().order_by('-valid_till').first()
```

Comment: no will have max date for each stock